# What is "ineedthispage"? Where is it coming from? It is killing the server

Tags: googlebot, apache2, performance, malware

I am seeing the following in my "access_log":

`ip.address.output.here - - [12/Dec/2019:15:17:07 +0000] "GET /pathto/article/15104133/?ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes&ineedthispage=yes HTTP/1.0" 200 817 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"`

It is causing major performance problems with my website (apache2, php7.3.12, mySQL5.7.28ubuntu). What is is and how can I stop it from accessing my server? It is causing the error `504 Gateway Time-out`.

Comment: Is this a WordPress site?   When I Google `ineedthispage=yes`, the results suggest it may be associated with WordPress malware.

Comment: Yes. It is a Wordpress site. What do I need to do to prevent this?

Comment: "what do I need to do to prevent this" check your site for malware.  There are numerous security plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's Googlebot crawling your page which would mean that ineedthispage is somewhere on your website.

Check the page source if the link is there hidden, also link most likely starts with &ineedthispage without http:// so it is creating internal loop

If you use Chrome you can press

> ctrl+u

To see the page source and then

> ctrl+f

To search for that text on the page source

Comment: Google search for the string indicates it may be malware related.  If malware is causing it, it is unlikely to be in the page source.  A lot of malware cloaks Googlebot.

Answer (score 1):

check the IP address source in WHOIS.  IF it is not Google, then simply block the IP.   Also, if the page does not exist, it would be worthwhile to add it, with an action of whatever IP address touches this page is automatically added to the block list for the site.